# How to represent SVG polygon in HTML using deffinition coming from POSTGIS ST_AsSVG function

Tags: python, django, svg, postgis, geodjango

In my django app I have postgis database. I tried to get a polygon as a SVG, so I could represent that polygon in HTML using the SVG standard.

I use the following query:
SELECT ST_AsSVG(geom) from country_limit cl where cl.id=3;

And It returned the following result:

```
M -85.941653 -12.285635 L -85.941653 -12.291673 -85.927577 -12.291673 -85.927577 -12.285635 Z
```

But when I try to represent that result inside an SVG, in HTML, It does not display the polygon.
Here is my code.

```
 <svg height="210" width="400">
   
    <path d="M -85.941653 -12.285635 L -85.941653 -12.291673 -85.927577 -12.291673 -85.927577 -12.285635 Z" />

 </svg>
```

How can I use the result from postgis ST_AsSVG to represent a geometry as SVG in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shape is

1. very very very small
2. outside the usual drawing area since it has negative co-ordinates

Both of these issues can be solved by using an appropriate viewBox.

```html
<svg height="210" width="400" viewBox="-85.942 -12.292 0.05 0.05">
   
    <path d="M -85.941653 -12.285635 L -85.941653 -12.291673 -85.927577 -12.291673 -85.927577 -12.285635 Z" />

 </svg>
```

Comment: I have never used SVG before. don't know what a viewBox is. Could you give an example of how to solve those Issues.

Comment: In what way is the code I posted not an example of how to solve those issues?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

Comment: sorry, i was reading your answer in my cellphone and I missed the code. Thank you so much for your help. Quick question: How can I apply the following style to the polygon: show only the perimeter, I mean the polygon lines in blue, and the interior in white (transparent), cause now is a black square

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#path